# How to count unique items in a table for a order?

Tags: mysql, count

I need to count unique number of items in the order.
Please take a look at the following example:

```
tablel
Order item
    1  111
    1  111
    1  123
    1  341
    1  341
    1  861
    2  999
    2  831
    3  731
    3  731
    3  721
    3  777
```

Expected result:

```
Order | Item Count    
-------------------
1     | 4    
2     | 2    
3     | 3
```

Comment: Using a reserved word as a column/table identifier is just asking for trouble. Also, you have no PRIMARY KEY - which may prove problematic in due course

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT order, COUNT(DISTINCT item)
FROM table1
GROUP BY order
```

A bit or word play.
I guess you mean the number of unique items in an order.

Answer (score -1):

```
select Order, count(item)
from table
group by order
```

Comment: please add some context around your query to explain how this will help the OP